# Scraping information from email to workflow

Tags: email, scraping, workflow

I have an email delivered to a specific inbox which contains a number of fields I need to scrape.

The fields will be subsequently fed into a workflow system.

For example:

```
From: example@other.com
To: specificinbox@mycompany.com
Subject: New starter notification

Message:

Name: John Smith
Start Date: 01/12/2016
End Date: 31/12/2016
..
```

Is there software which could automatically listen to or poll the email account for new emails, and extract these fields (`John Smith`, `01/12/2016`, `31/12/2016`) or dump the entire email into a text file for further scraping?

Alternatively, a workflow system which can interpret emails out of the box.

Other information:

- The format of the email is fixed.
- Email server is Exchange Server 2013.
- The mail server isn't IMAP enabled :(
- The system sending the email does not provide an API or web service to extract the information.
- Preferably this should run on Windows Server 2016.
- Price would depend on what else the software can do. We are looking at a full-fledged workflow tool, such as Alfresco/Anypoint, but I'm not sure how email input will feed in.

Comment: If your email server also allows you to fetch mail using IMAP you will open up a lot more options.  Presumably you want something to run on windows?

Comment: @meuh The mail server isn't IMAP enabled :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python](https://www.python.org) can either use the [exchangelib](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib) library to communicate directly with your Exchange 2013 Server, *(Supports Microsoft Exchange 2007-2016 Server or Office365)* via Exchange Web Services (EWS) *unless your administator has disabled this feature*, or you use the [Win32Com](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32) library as demonstrated in [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077625/reading-e-mails-from-outlook-with-python-through-mapi) in conjunction with your local Outlook installation.

Either will get the email for you and python has numerous built in tools for parsing the text into fields.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Python & exchangelib are cross platform
- Win32Com is Windows only *unsurprisingly* & relies on you having Exchange installed on your computer.